# Enable HTTP2 protocol for embedded Jetty server

Tags: jetty

I have tried this :

```
    SecurityManager securityManager = 
    SecurityManager.getSecurityManager();
    SslContextFactory.Server sslContextFactory = securityManager.             
    getSslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setSniRequired(false);
    sslContextFactory.setRenegotiationAllowed(false);
    sslContextFactory.setHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    sslContextFactory.setCipherComparator(HTTP2Cipher.COMPARATOR);
    sslContextFactory.setUseCipherSuitesOrder(true);
    
    httpConfig.setSecurePort(port);
    httpConfig.setSecureScheme("https");
    httpConfig.setSendServerVersion(false);
    SecureRequestCustomizer src = new SecureRequestCustomizer();
    src.setSniHostCheck(false);
    httpConfig.addCustomizer(src);
    HttpConfiguration httpsConfig = new 
 HttpConfiguration(httpConfig);
    
    connector = new ServerConnector(server,
    new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, 
    HttpVersion.HTTP_2.asString()),  new HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory(httpConfig),new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
```

But I still get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No protocol factory for SSL next protocol: 'HTTP/2.0' in ServerConnector@7efd28bd{SSL, (ssl, h2)}{0.0.0.0:8443}